# What is the difference between Observable.create and fromPublisher?

Tags: rx-java2

Changing `Observable.create` to `Observable.fromPublisher` in the source below does not work. (If sample is not present, all are subscribed, but if sample is present, nothing is subscribed.)

What is the difference between Observable.create and fromPublisher?

```java
import io.reactivex.Observable;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<String> o = Observable.create(s -> {
            new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                    s.onNext("Hello Observable.fromPublisher() A" + i);
                    s.onNext("Hello Observable.fromPublisher() B" + i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                s.onComplete();
            }).start();
        });
        o
                .sample(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromPublisher` requires a properly implemented `org.reactivestreams.Publisher` that honors the [rules](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#specification). These `Publisher`s typically come from 3rd party libraries or APIs.

`create` has built in infrastructure to convert a simpler emitter-style API to an `Observable` so that the developer doesn't have to worry that much of the underlying protocol.

Also may I direct your attention to the javadoc of [`fromPublisher`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#fromPublisher-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-):

> The Publisher must follow the Reactive-Streams specification. Violating the specification may result in undefined behavior.
>
> If possible, use create(ObservableOnSubscribe) to create a source-like Observable instead.
>
> Note that even though Publisher appears to be a functional interface, it is not recommended to implement it through a lambda as the specification requires state management that is not achievable with a stateless lambda.